# How to make an usb-stick to format a computer?

Tags: xubuntu

In xubuntu, how can I make a usb-stick that formats my second computer's hard-disk? It looks like the hard disk is some how messed, and I think it might be easiest to reinstall everything. UEFI seems to work fine.

Comment: The easiest way is to download a live distribution. But it seems like an X-Y problem, you have some problem with your disk. Most installers let you delete the partitions, and formatting somthing before deleting doesn't make sense.

Comment: So is it A) HDD 2 on your PC is 'messed' or B) the HDD on your PC #2 is 'messed'? Also, what do you mean by 'messed'? Please click [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

To re-install an OS, you just re-install it, no need to reformat (actually you can't format a modern hard-disk. You could recreate the file-system, or partition table, but the OS installer should do this.) There are some live OS images that you could use to test your hard-disk (to see if there is a hard-ware problem).

If you want to do what is in the headline of you question, then any live Gnu/Linux OS will be able to do it.